# Akka Cluster not connecting - AWS Ecs - Fargate

Tags: scala, akka, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, akka-cluster

I am trying to run an akka cluster on AWS Ecs by Fargate. So far, not so good. Network connectivity is open inbound and outbound on all port between fargate instances

I start an instance without seeds
After 5 minutes, i check with the aws sdk the list of services and, since there isnt anything else running appart from myself, I become the cluster leader.

I start then a second instance, do the same thing. This time, this instance detect that there is a service running and tries to connect to its cluster.

I tried this configuration, on the first instance :

```
{
   "remote":{
      "artery":{
         "bind":{
            "hostname":"172.31.74.127",
            "port":25520
         },
         "canonical":{
            "hostname":"172.31.74.127",
            "port":25520
         }
      }
   }
```

Also this one

```
{
   "remote":{
      "artery":{
         "bind":{
            "hostname":"172.31.74.127",
            "port":25520
         },
         "canonical":{
            "hostname":"0.0.0.0",
            "port":25520
         }
      }
   }
```

Neither worked, it should be fairly straight forward but I must be missing something because i get this one the second instance :

```
12:59:01.574 [cms-api-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] WARN akka.stream.Materializer - [outbound connection to [akka://cms-api@172.31.74.127:25520], control stream] Upstream failed, cause: StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(172.31.74.127:25520,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired
```

and then :

```
12:59:16.460 [cms-api-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15] WARN akka.remote.artery.Association - Outbound control stream to [akka://cms-api@172.31.74.127:25520] failed. Restarting it. akka.remote.artery.OutboundHandshake$HandshakeTimeoutException: Handshake with [akka://cms-api@172.31.74.127:25520] did not complete within 20000 ms.
```

Happy to hear from someone who had this working :) Thank you for you help!

Comment: With Fargate there isn't any `instance` so not sure what you mean by "Network connectivity is open inbound and outbound on all port between fargate instances". Traffic is controlled at the task level via Security Groups that you configured for said tasks. Can you double check of the SG associated to your two tasks can allow inbound/outbound?

Comment: yes, it is what I meant. The SG on the task is open both ways